# Illegal use of mov/xchg operators

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I'm taking an assembler course at school and they asked this question:

What are illegal use of the next operations:

```
1.    mov   bh,al
2.    mov   dh,cx 
3.    mov   bh,bh 
4.    mov   cl, 4F2h 
5.    mov   cx, 002dh 
6.    xchg  var1, var2
```

What are the situations where the operations with `mov` and `xchg` are not legal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certain combinations of operands are legal, and certain combinations aren't.  Most notably, both operands must be of the same size, and at least one operand must be a register.  I think those facts combined should suffice to let you determine which of the above are legal and which are not.

Comment: I would only add that your assembly reference will tell you which combinations are legal and which aren't (or your textbook).

Comment: Actually, what you want to understand is the instruction set architecture, because ultimately the assembler must produce real instructions.   If you want write an "assembly code line" that seems coherent, but doens't match any real instruction, expect the assembler to complain.  So by knowing what the instruction set allows, you can know what are valid assembly language lines.  (Also note that there may be many available assembler tools for a particular instruction set, and they will egregiously different syntax for writing instructions, but the underlying target is the same for all of them.)

Comment: so regarding to the top operations and based on what you said the only one that are not legal is #2 and #6? how do i know the size of 4F2h and 002dh? this is the only info they provided in the question..@IraBaxter

Comment: Also, from what I understand in the book, the operation 'mov var2, 10h' is legal...and one of them is memory slot, and the other is value..but non is register. are you sure that one of them have to be register? maybe only in xchg one of them have to be register  @IraBaxter

Comment: be careful about the difference between "illegal" and "not producing the expected result".  And correct,  mov [addr],imm  is valid

Comment: #2 and #6 aren't valid instructions for the x86.  #4 *should not* be valid, because the operand value is too big to fit into the register.   Following @Bushmill's comment, remember you are giving this line of text to the assembler, and it decides what to do with it.  It could (stupidly) ignore the bits above what is allowable and generate the equivalent of "mov cl, 0F2h".  So, "illegal" vs. "not producing the expected result".  Most assemblers are pretty stupid; expect to be surprised like this with a real assembler.  And yes, its a head scratcher when it happens.

Comment: @Nir: Sorry, I forgot that `mov` allows immediate to memory, though in that case it's necessary to explicitly specify the size of the memory operand.  And instructions to move to/from segment registers require the other operand to be a memory operand or a non-segment register, but disallow immediate.  Segments were actually a brilliant concept in 8086, except for the relative lack of segment registers; unfortunately, the 80286 segment architecture made things worse, and the 80386 didn't fix the biggest problems in the 80286 design.